# Get PowerBI access token using UserAssertion

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App with Easy Auth enabled. I want to get an access token to access to power bi with the permissions of the logged in user, so that user can directly access power bi from frontend. 
I have registered an application on Azure AD with permissions to power bi and I created a HTTP triggered endpoint to return the access token to frontend.

I don't have any username or password in the function app, only the ID token of the user. Is there any way I can require an access token to access power bi on behalf of the user using the ID token or UserAssertion?

My implementation is here:

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize");

var res = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", 
clientId, new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserAssertion(idToken)).ConfigureAwait(false);

return new OkObjectResult(new { Token = res.AccessToken });
```

But when I try to run this code, it throws me this exception 
`System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: GetPowerBiToken. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory: AADSTS50027: JWT token is invalid or malformed.`

Is this the correct way to get the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you have a public client to log in users. This client will call APIs on the Azure function app and your function app will call PowerBi to do some tasks on behalf of users who logged in on your public client.

In this whole process, you should register two Azure AD apps :

1.An App for your public client, you should grant it delegated permission to access your Azure function App so that users could login and get an access token to call your function app .

2.An app for your Azure function app,you should grant it delegated permission related to powerbi, so that it could call powerbi apis on behalf of users.

So pls follow the steps below to finish this process :

1.On your client side , login users and get an access token which requested resources is your function app.

2.Call your function app with that access token so that your function app could use [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) to get an access token to call powerbi resources.
I have tested this process in an simple console app and it works perfectly for me, and the code is what you are looking for I think :

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureADUserAssertion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var functionClientId = "<function azure ad app id>";
            var functionSecret = "<function azure ad app secret>";
            var functionCred = new ClientCredential(functionClientId, functionSecret);

            var access_token_from_client_side = "<access token value>";
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/");

            var res = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
            functionCred, new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserAssertion(access_token_from_client_side, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer")).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine(  res.AccessToken );
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Result : 
[image]

Check this token :

[image]

Hope it helps .

Comment: when I used ID token instead of access token it works, thanks :)

Comment: @Stanley, how to get access token for first app (What should be the scope) . I followed ur steps, still getting Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The provided signature value did not match the expected signature value.,

Comment: I got it working. may be i ll post detailed information, how i did..